# htaccess rewrite-rule not matching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have a problem since i changed my hosting. The new hosting package has problems with a simple rule, which worked before perfect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# NOT MATCHING
RewriteRule ^pro/(.*)/(.*)/$ pro.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]

# MATCHING
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ pro.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When i call f.e. "**www.example.com/pro/350/658a/**" the first rule is not machting but the second one. Doe somebody has an idea why its not working on the new hosting-package?

Answer (score 0):

`.*` matches pretty much everything. Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# NOT MATCHING
RewriteRule ^pro/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pro.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]

# MATCHING
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pro.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
```